# .gexf -format node graph visualization

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

To visualize a node graph [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org) looks fantastic. I tried some examples but can't get my graph to display. I used example code and tried to plug in my .gexf file, but nothing displays. This is what I took from the [Sigma.js example](http://sigmajs.org/examples/gexf_example.html) :

```
function init() {
  // Instanciate sigma.js and customize rendering :
  var sigInst = sigma.init(document.getElementById('sigma-example')).drawingProperties({
    defaultLabelColor: '#fff',
    defaultLabelSize: 14,
    defaultLabelBGColor: '#fff',
    defaultLabelHoverColor: '#000',
    labelThreshold: 6,
    defaultEdgeType: 'curve'
  }).graphProperties({
    minNodeSize: 0.5,
    maxNodeSize: 5,
    minEdgeSize: 1,
    maxEdgeSize: 1
  }).mouseProperties({
    maxRatio: 32
  });

  // Parse a GEXF encoded file to fill the graph
  // (requires "sigma.parseGexf.js" to be included)
  sigInst.parseGexf('donornet.gexf');

  // Draw the graph :
  sigInst.draw();
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
} else {
  window.onload = init;
}
```

I replaced the .gexf file with my own donornet.gexf file and saved it as donornet.js. I then used code from this [example](http://neosigma.herokuapp.com/index.html) (from [Max De Marzi](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/04/12/using-sigma-js-with-neo4j/)), which I replaced with my donornet.js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Donornet and Sigma.js Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sigma.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sigma.parseGexf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sigma.forceatlas2.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="neo_sigma.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Donornet and Sigma.js Example</h1>
        <div class="buttons-container">
        <button class="btn" id="stop-layout">Stop Layout</button>
        <button class="btn" id="rescale-graph">Rescale Graph</button>
    </div>
        <div class="span12 sigma-parent" id="sigma-example-parent">
    <div class="sigma-expand" id="sigma-example"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="donornet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All files are in the same folder. parseGexf.js is in the same folder as donornet.js and donornet.gexf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to save .gexf file as a .js file. Just leave it as a gexf file and upload it into the script's folder. Remove the line with `<script src="donornet.js">`. Try to run again. If it doesn't work, also remove the buttons div. Check out the source on http://noduslabs.com/socialplayer/smmrussia/