# XMLHTTPRequest Error From Sigma.js when trying to run it in Chrome [Seems to be unique to way it is run]

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

Issue I'm facing: there is no graph D:

What I'm trying to do: Copy this locally run it. http://sigmajs.org/examples/gexf_example.html

What i'm getting when I try to emulate the webpage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktirm.png

When I run it in Firefox I also get nothing, and I'm not sure why...

**Similar questions:**

This is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572429/sigma-parsegexf-js-got-xmlhttprequest-exception-error which did not recieve any answers :(

there is this too but I don't understand what exactly he did ... [Graph visualization with Sigma.js: way over my head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823134/javascript-sigma-js-visualization-way-over-my-head)

How can I fix this / will it only work on a web server?

Thanks!

I tried to use some solution and change  `gexfhttp.open('GET', gexfPath, false);` to  `gexfhttp.open('GET', gexfPath, true);`  but found no difference

Relevant Code:

Javascript (taken from sigma.js.org)
sigma.parseGexf.js http://pastie.org/5133355 (modified with the 'solution' above)
prettify.js: http://sigmajs.org/js/prettify.js
sigma.min: http://sigmajs.org/js/sigma.min.js

CSS
http://sigmajs.org/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://sigmajs.org/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
http://sigmajs.org/css/style.css
http://sigmajs.org/css/prettify.css

HTML File I'm running (from sigmajs.org again)
http://pastie.org/5133367 also at http://sigmajs.org/examples/gexf_example.html

Comment: locally run it means what. Off file protocol or localhost?

Comment: means I want to run it from my local google chrome or firefox just by opening a file ...

Comment: I mean if I can get it to work by somehow hosting something .. then ok?

Answer (score 0):

Run a local [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) or IIS and you run it off localhost.